# How can I get a wide image right below the title of a twocolumn document followed by twocolumn text?

Tags: floats, two-column, tcolorbox, includegraphics, wide-image

I want to have a onecolumn image on the first page right below the title of a twocolumn document. The image should span the text width.

I am not using the `multicols` package because it causes problems with the text placement later on in the document.

My code looks like follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[top=10mm,bottom=15mm,left=15mm,right=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.7}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{-7pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-1pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\font\myfont=cmr12 at 26pt

\title{{\myfont 'title}\vspace{-2ex}}
\author{'name'\\
        \texttt{'e-mail'}
        \and
        'name'\\
        \texttt{'e-mail'}}
\date{\vspace{-1ex}'Date'\vspace{-3ex}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image.jpg}
%This would not work of course. Would need to be onecolumn.

\begin{tcolorbox}
...
\end{tcolorbox}
...
```

The problem with this is that one of the following text boxes, created at the top of the second column on the first page, overlaps with the image.

I did try to use `figure*` before but it would completely separate the image from the text boxes and appear on random pages.

Is there a way to fix this? Again, I do not want to use `multicols` as it causes lots of other problems.

Would it make sense not to use floats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX SX!

You can use the `strip` environment from `cuted` (`sttools` bundle). Of course the image is no more floating, but this is irrelevant if you want it right after the title:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[top=10mm,bottom=15mm,left=15mm,right=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum, cuted}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.7}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{-7pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-1pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\font\myfont=cmr12 at 26pt

\title{{\myfont 'title}\vspace{-2ex}}
\author{'name'\\
        \texttt{'e-mail'}
        \and
        'name'\\
        \texttt{'e-mail'}}
\date{\vspace{-1ex}'Date'\vspace{-3ex}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{strip}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{SanRomano-all}
\end{strip}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add the image to the `\date`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[top=10mm,bottom=15mm,left=15mm,right=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.7}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{-7pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-1pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\font\myfont=cmr12 at 26pt

\title{{\myfont 'title}\vspace{-2ex}}
\author{'name'\\
        \texttt{'e-mail'}
        \and
        'name'\\
        \texttt{'e-mail'}}
\date{\vspace{-1ex}'Date'\vspace{2ex}\\
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: full page]

---

With this degree of customization, one wonders why use `\maketitle` at all?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[top=10mm,bottom=15mm,left=15mm,right=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.7}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{-7pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-1pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\font\myfont=cmr12 at 26pt

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[{\begin{center}
  {\myfont 'title}\par
  \vskip.75em\vskip-2ex
  {\large\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
    'name'\\
    \texttt{'e-mail'}
    \and
    'name'\\
    \texttt{'e-mail'}
    \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1.5em\vskip-1ex
  {\large 'Date'\par}
  \vskip2ex
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \end{center}}]

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```